# Sum a list of variables in R

Tags: r, variables, sum

I am trying to sum up a list of variables.

```
qdisgust <- c(2,3,5,8,12,17,18,22,23,25,28,29,31,33)
vqdisgust <- list()
n    <- length(qdisgust)
lhs  <- paste("mydata$Disgust_", qdisgust, sep="")
eq   <- paste("vqdisgust <- c(lhs)")
eval(parse(text=eq))
```

I sucessfully get all the variables in the list, but then am not able to get the sum of them. I assume there would be a way even simpler to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: the `qdisgust` is a `vector`  Where is `mydata`?  Please provide a reproducible example and you won't possible need the `eval(parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are looking to get the `sum` of multiple columns in 'mydata', we can use `colSums`

```
colSums(mydata)
```

If `qdisgust` is the index of columns, either

```
colSums(mydata[paste0("Disgust_", qdisgust)])
```

or

```
colSums(mydata[grep("Disgust_", names(mydata))])
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! This seems to be going in the right direction. However I am getting the following error:

    colSums(mydata[paste0("Disgust_", qdisgust)])


Error in `[.data.frame`(mydata, paste0("Disgust_", qdisgust)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @Chris It is based on the code you showed.  The `paste0` will get the column names that could be present in the dataset.  Please check if those columns are there in your data.

Comment: Good point, @akrun. I get now the following error: 
> colSums(mydata[paste0("Disgust_", qdisgust)])
Error in colSums(mydata[paste0("Disgust_", qdisgust)]) : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: @Chris That means the columns you want to sum is not numeric.  Please check the `str(mydata)` and if it is not numeric, convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric` if it is character.  or if it is `factor`, then `as.numeric(as.character(`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Akrun! Now it works perfectly!